# Heroku - apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app is working fine in local, and even earlier this morning, I was able to get it to show in Heroku. However, now that it is pretty much done, I get that pesky message!

Here is the Heroku log. I am not sure how to troubleshoot it:

```
2012-11-20T19:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in  `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4485189738011654672_31063660'
2012-11-20T19:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2012-11-20T19:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2012-11-20T19:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
 2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (images/apple-touch-    icon- 144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled):
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina  display: -->
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'images/apple-touch- icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png',  :sizes => '144x144' %>
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in  `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4485189738011654672_31063660'
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 19:50:03  +0000
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within  layouts/application (0.3ms)
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-11-20T19:50:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2012-11-20T19:50:08+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/  host=thenewoutfitproject.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=thenewoutfitproject.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=6ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 19:50:31 +0000
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled):
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4485189738011654672_31063660'
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>
2012-11-20T19:50:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled):
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 19:54:14 +0000
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4485189738011654672_31063660'
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:54:14+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=7ms connect=32ms service=80ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled):
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4485189738011654672_31063660'
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 19:55:36 +0000
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:55:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 19:59:39 +0000
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled):
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T19:59:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4485189738011654672_31063660'
```

I am using twitter_bootstrap.
 --- Updating after the initial fixes:

I got heroku to start running, but then it stops when I get ti to display a parameter from a  database. This is all working locally. I couldn't find what could be the issue. Some people said to restart heroku, which I did, to no avail.

Here is the new log.

```
2012-11-20T21:39:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-11-20T21:39:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-11-20T21:39:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-11-20T21:39:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-11-20T21:39:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-11-20T21:40:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=4ms connect=21ms service=185ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-11-20T21:40:03+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-fbdaadfcf0bb7bb383cee6f4c1e1c57b.js host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=6ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-11-20T21:40:03+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-9b102f3d65ffd824f6d66380b37af1d3.css host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-11-20T21:40:05+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/newstyle host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2ms connect=14ms service=505ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-11-20T21:40:12+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/styles host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=49ms status=302 bytes=106
2012-11-20T21:40:12+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/styles/3 host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=3ms connect=18ms service=99ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-20T21:41:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-11-20T21:41:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-11-20T21:41:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 29507`
2012-11-20T21:41:29+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-11-20T21:41:29+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-11-20T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-11-20T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-11-20T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:29507, CTRL+C to stop
2012-11-20T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
2012-11-20T21:41:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-11-20T21:41:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 21:41:36 +0000
2012-11-20T21:41:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-11-20T21:41:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (9.3ms)
2012-11-20T21:41:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 230.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2012-11-20T21:41:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-9b102f3d65ffd824f6d66380b37af1d3.css host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=41ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-11-20T21:41:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-fbdaadfcf0bb7bb383cee6f4c1e1c57b.js host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=106ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-11-20T21:41:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StylesController#new as HTML
2012-11-20T21:41:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/newstyle" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 21:41:40 +0000
2012-11-20T21:41:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered styles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (696.9ms)
2012-11-20T21:41:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1030ms (Views: 711.3ms | ActiveRecord: 29.8ms)
2012-11-20T21:41:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered styles/_form.html.erb (678.3ms)
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/styles" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 21:41:48 +0000
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StylesController#create as HTML
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WEpGdTD2B9P9pJOelseHsxDwVxU3ph3sbDeZPWPNXHc=", "style"=>{"bodytype"=>"Hourglass", "need"=>"Office", "texture"=>"Rich", "color"=>"Bright", "statement"=>"Shoe"}, "commit"=>"Create Recommendation"}
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://mapmystyle.herokuapp.com/styles/4
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 35.7ms)
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/styles/4" for 66.25.149.26 at 2012-11-20 21:41:48 +0000
2012-11-20T21:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StylesController#show as HTML
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 509ms
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/styles_controller.rb:28:in `show'
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass):
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-20T21:41:49+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/styles/4 host=mapmystyle.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=641ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Please help!

Comment: It looks like it's looking for the apple-touch-icon but it's not there. Are you sure you put it in your assets folder?

Comment: Have you specified the apple-touch-icon in your precompiled assets? *Are* you precompiling assets?

Comment: It seems that your assets aren't pre-compiled. Do you see any errors related to "assets" or "pre-compilation" when you push your app to heroku? If so, check your `config/application.rb` and make sure you have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says

```
images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled
```

That is the error.

Put this line in you config/application.rb file

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

If you have other .js or .css files that are not required in application.js and application.css

For instance public.js and public.css

Add this line to the production.rb file ( Added the comment also. )

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( public.js public.css  )
```

Run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on your local code

Do you get any errors?

If not.

Commit the changes and deploy to heroku

Comment: Thanks, that worked, kinda. But I also had to deal with the images for apple, as suggested in the comments above. :-( Now I am getting a different kind of error, that I am not getting on local: Completed 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: First google you the line that displays the error. If you do not find an answer, update you question with the new error log. Sometimes Heroku deployment can be difficult. If we go trough the errors you have, we might help others.

Comment: Just made the update to the question. I checked on the heroku console and it seems Heroku doesn't even recognize the recommender model.

Comment: app/controllers/styles_controller.rb:28:in `show'
 NoMethodError (undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: You have an error in you styles_controller line 28. It is probably a typo. The problem is with the word "link". You also have a DEPRECATION WARNING on one of you plugins. Try to find the gem version of this plugin.